# Erlang LS in Visual Studio Code can't find include_lib

Tags: visual-studio-code, erlang, erlang-ls

My project is a rebar 3 `app` project, i.e. the code is in the `src` directory, the dependencies are in `_build/default/lib/`, and includes are in `include` and `_build/default/lib/*/include`.

I have this include statement in on one of my source files: `-include_lib("common_erlang/include/common.hrl")`.

My erlang_ls.config file is in the root directory of the project, this is the content:

```
apps_dirs:
  - "_build/default/lib/*"
include_dirs:
  - "_build/default/lib/*/include"
  - "include
```

With the include statement as above, I get the error `can't find include lib`, but the project compiles. If I change the include statement to `-include_lib("common.hrl").` the error in vscode goes away, but I get an error when I compile (obviously).

I tried changing the erlang_ls.config file line `- "_build/default/lib/*/include"` to `- "_build/default/lib/"` in case the `common_erlang/include` part of the include statment was causing a problem, but it still couldn't find it.

Is there a problem with my Erlang LS configuration? I copied it from https://erlang-ls.github.io/configuration/ (the config for rebar3 projects). I tried unistatlling and reinstalling the Erlang LS extension but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

This config worked for me:

```yaml
apps_dirs:
  - "_build/default/lib/*"
include_dirs:
  - "_build/default/lib/*/include"
  - "_build/default/lib"
  - "include"
```

Perhaps the trailing slash you had in `_build/default/lib/` was an issue.